# What is the appropriate status code for NotBeforeError JWT Error?

Tags: authentication, jwt, resources, token, http-status-code-403

When I googled [NotBeforeError JWT Error](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#notbeforeerror), it says that it is an error that occurs when you try to use the issued token while it has not yet been activated.

When you have an inactive token, you do not have permission to access a specific resource, so I thought it might be 403.

If the issued token has not been activated yet, it will not pass authentication, so I think that 400 or other codes may be more suitable than 403.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is a 401 error. I use 401 for situations where the request does not have a valid credential. In your case, there is no valid token. I reserve 403 for situations where there is a valid token in the request, but it doesn't have the required permissions.

The difference is in how the client should react to these errors:

- When you get a 401 it is information to the client that the user needs to authenticate. The reason why is not relevant — maybe the token has expired, maybe there's no token, or maybe it violates `nbf`.
- When you get a 403 it is information that the user needs to present stronger credentials. Usually in this case, reauthenticating won't help and the user needs other ways of fixing the problem.